# python given 2 datetimes get how many hours are between 24:00 - 06:00

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to calculate if the range of datetimes given, get how many night time hours goes through 24:00-06:00.

Example:

If given dates are Aug 27, 23:00 - Aug 29, 01:00 ( 25 hours). so the answer should be 7 hours night time.

OR

If given dates are Aug 27, 05:00 - Aug 29, 07:00 (50 hours ), so the answer should be 13 hours night time.

I know i have to calculate the difference in days

```
diff_days = abs(convert_end_date - convert_start_date).days
```

and then make a condition if those times are in the range of the 2 given datetimes.

i will place it in a while loop because it will depend of how many days are.

Hope it is clear enough cause i don't know how else to explain more simple then this...

This is the code that i have, but it doesn't include if its more then 24 hours...

```
convert_start_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(start_date)
convert_end_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(end_date)

min_midnight = datetime.combine(convert_start_date, time.min)
next_day = min_midnight + dt.timedelta(days=1)
six_oclock_next_day = next_day + dt.timedelta(hours=6)


# if between 00:00 - 06:00
    if min_midnight < convert_start_date < six_oclock_today and min_midnight < convert_end_date < six_oclock_today:
        night_hours = (convert_end_date - convert_start_date).seconds / 60
        print(night_hours / 60)
        print("If start date and end date between midnight and 6am")

    # if start date between 00:00 - 06:00 and end date not
    if min_midnight < convert_start_date < six_oclock_today and (
    not min_midnight < convert_end_date < six_oclock_today):
        night_hours = (six_oclock_today - convert_start_date).seconds / 60
        print(night_hours / 60)
        print("If start date between midnight and 6 am and not the end date")

    # if between 06:00 - 2400
    if six_oclock_today < convert_start_date < next_day and six_oclock_today < convert_end_date < next_day:
        day_hours = (convert_end_date - convert_start_date).seconds / 60
        print(day_hours / 60)
        print("If start date between 6am and midnight")

    # if start date between 06:00 - 24:00 and end date not
    if six_oclock_today < convert_start_date < next_day and (not six_oclock_today < convert_end_date < next_day):
        day_hours = (next_day - convert_start_date).seconds / 60
        print(day_hours / 60)
        print("If end date between 6am and midnight")

    # if start date between next day 00:00 - 06:00
    if next_day < convert_start_date < six_oclock_next_day:
        night_hours = (six_oclock_next_day - convert_start_date).seconds / 60
        print(night_hours / 60)
        print("If start date lower then next day 6 oclock")

    # if end date between next day 00:00 - 06:00
    if next_day < convert_end_date < six_oclock_next_day:
        night_hours = (convert_end_date - next_day).seconds / 60
        print(night_hours / 60)
        print("If end date between next day midnight and 6 oclock")

    # if end date next day after tomorrow 06:00-24:00
    if six_oclock_next_day < convert_end_date:
        night_hours = 6.0 * 60
        day_hours = day_hours + (convert_end_date - six_oclock_next_day).seconds / 60
        print(day_hours / 60 + night_hours)
        print("If end date the day after after 6 am")
```

Thank you, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code can do it, with some limitations:

```
def count_hours_between_00_and_06(start_date, end_date):
    if end_date < start_date:
        start_date, end_date = end_date, start_date

    start_hour = start_date.hour
    end_hour = end_date.hour
    if start_date.date() == end_date.date():
        #dates are in the same day

        if start_hour > 6:
            return 0
        else:
            end_hour = end_hour if end_hour < 6 else 6
            return end_hour - start_hour
    else:
        days_delta = (end_date.date() - start_date.date).days - 1
        total_hours = 0
        if start_hour < 6:
            total_hours += 6 - start_hour
        total_hours += end_hour if end_hour < 6 else 6
        total_hours += days_delta * 6
        return total_hours
```

note that it doesn't factor in the minutes and seconds part of the `datetime` object, it also doesn't take care of timezones and daylight savings but other than those it does what you want

i should also note that the math done is simplified since your range is 0am-6am if you would change the hours you want to count say to 1am-7am you would need more complex math to figure out the hours